# configure store procedure in mysql with IF ELSE

Tags: mysql, procedures

I am trying to create a procedure that will insert two columns into a table.   I need to create a procedure that I could use in vb.net for creating mailboxes

The procedure that I created is:

```
PROCEDURE 'create_mail' (IN em VARCHAR(20),IN pas VARCHAR(20),OUT ans INT )
INSERT INTO 'mail.mailbx' ('email','pasword') VALUES ('em', ENCRYPT('pas'))
```

When I am executing in phpMyAdmin its work, it creates columns that I choose in 'mail.mailbx', but I  need to check if `em` exist in 'mail.mailbx', if exist create `ans` as integer = 'o' or something like that, if no exist run "insert into..." and create  'ans' as integer ='1'. from vb.net I will be create msgbox's that let me know if mailbox was created or not created from parameter 'ans'.

Comment: Why not simply create a UNIQUE index on column email.. the INSERT fails if the same email adress is being used twice

Comment: Hi.thanks for your replay.do u have some examples how can I do it?

Comment: You can run query like this - `ALTER TABLE mail.mailbx ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK1(email)`, see MySQL documentation about CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE. Or you can use GUI tool to do it in design mode.

Comment: hi)i read mysql documentation and some forums,and i did it :) the procedure is: CREATE PROCEDURE  `create_mail` ( IN  `em1` VARCHAR( 80 ) , IN  `pas1` VARCHAR( 80 ) , OUT `err` VARCHAR( 30 ) )

Comment: BEGIN declare exit  handler for sqlstate '23000' set err=1;

iNSERT INTO `mail`.`users` (`email`, `password`) 
                             vALUES (em1,pas1);
set  err=0;
end  .So i set primary column 'email',i declared handler for duplicated culumns..work fine)in vb.net  i create js alerts thas showing me  if mail created or not created,and other errors i see as sql eror with TRY WITH  thanks a lot